# Parsing a MySQL base in Python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, parsing

I have a table in a MySQL database with this schema:

```
ID:integer increment
URL: string
Name: string
Path: string
Downloaded: tinyint 1
NotFound: tinyint 1
```

I have Python 3.5.2 installed. And I have to make a python script which connects to the base, field URL. Link contains a picture. I need this script to loop through all URLs with pictures and save the pictures to Path with names in Name.

Also script should put flag NotFound if needed.
If there's any other exception, then this script should continue without any flag.

Limit 1000, offset 1000

That's my first task with Python ever after reading my first book 'Introducing Python: Modern Computing in Simple Packages' by Bill Lubanovic. So, it's quite hard to do the task. I've googled for the info but cannot aggregate the info and understand how to make that script. Any tips on how to make it will be much appreciated. Thank you.

All I've understood so far is:

```
import pymysql

conn= pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='', database='test')
cursor=db.cursor()
```

Would be nice to get at least some general advice or links for self-education.

Comment: `cursor.execute("SOME SQL QUERY")`

Comment: if you import `pymysql` then start education with `pymysql` documentation - http://pymysql.readthedocs.io